# How to access nested objects inside JSON?

Tags: php, json, laravel

This is my Controller:

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $soapClient = new \SoapClient('http://187.32.223.233/UraIntegrada/Siacon/ConsorcioServices.asmx?WSDL');
        $params = array(
                'sGrupo' => "0".$request->sGrupo,
                'iCota' => $request->iCota,
                'iIdERP' => $request->iIdERP
        );
        $response = $soapClient->ROS_ExtratoContaCorrente($params);
        foreach ($response as $dados) {
            $dado = json_decode(json_encode($dados), true);
        }
        // return $dado;
        // die();

        return view('layouts.extrato', compact('dado'));
    }
```

And this is how I am rendring data on blade:

```
<div class="col">
     Nome: {{ $dado['NOME-CLIENTE'] }}<br>
     Rua: {{ $dado['NOME-LOGRADOURO'] }}, Nº{{ $dado['NUMERO-LOGRADOURO'] }}<br>
     Bairro: {{ $dado['BAIRRO'] }}<br>
     Cidade: {{ $dado['CIDADE'] }} - UF: {{ $dado['UF'] }}<br>
     CEP: {{ $dado['CEP'] }}<br>
     Telefone: {{ $dado['NUMERO-TELEFONE'] }}
 </div>
```

How do I access a JSON nested object with Laravel?

Can access via $dados['NOME-CLIENTE'], but don´t know how to access the next nested object 'PARCELAS-PAGAS`->PARCELA-PAGA->NUMERO-PARCELA

```
{
  "NOME-CLIENTE": "JANE DOE",
  "CODIGO-GRUPO": "06275",
  "NUMERO-COTA": 45,
  "NOME-LOGRADOURO": "JUNIOR STREET",
  "NUMERO-LOGRADOURO": "519",
  "BAIRRO": "PRESIDENTE ROOSEVELT",
  "CIDADE": "UBERLANDIA",
      "PARCELAS-PAGAS": {
           "PARCELA-PAGA": [
                {
                 "NUMERO-PARCELA": 17,
                 "DATA-VENCIMENTO": "20190108",
                },
```

Now I want to access the 'NUMERO-PARCELA' node, but don´t know how to do it in Laravel

Comment: `PARCELA-PAGA` is an array, so you should use it as `PARCELA-PAGA[0]->NUMERO-PARCELA`.

Comment: Hi @Laerte, i think is a little more than that, but it is my fault, didn´t explain all:
WIll edit myquestion...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the overall object is an associative array, which it appears to be from your example code, then you'd access your property like this:

```
$dado["PARCELAS-PAGAS"]["PARCELA-PAGA"][0]["NUMERO-PARCELA"]
```

The `[0]` index will get you the first item in the "PARCELA-PAGA" array (this bit is a numeric array rather than an associative array).

Here's a runnable demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/54097b7213fbfe598c67a2c08b43d1e72ba2ede6

Of course if you expect there might be multiple items, you'd be better to use a loop to fetch each on in turn, assuming you want to get them all.

P.S. Forget about it being JSON, once it's been de-serialized into a variable then it works like any other PHP variable. You can always use `var_dump()` to look at the structure of the variable once it's become a PHP variable.

Answer (score 1):

The key `PARCELA-PAGA` is an array. You need to loop over it.

For example:

```
$json = '{
  "NOME-CLIENTE": "JANE DOE",
  "CODIGO-GRUPO": "06275",
  "NUMERO-COTA": 45,
  "NOME-LOGRADOURO": "JUNIOR STREET",
  "NUMERO-LOGRADOURO": "519",
  "BAIRRO": "PRESIDENTE ROOSEVELT",
  "CIDADE": "UBERLANDIA",
  "PARCELAS-PAGAS": {
        "PARCELA-PAGA": [
            {
                "NUMERO-PARCELA": 17,
                "DATA-VENCIMENTO": "20190108"
            }
        ]
  }
}';

$dado = json_decode($json, true); 

$parcelaPaga = $dado['PARCELAS-PAGAS']['PARCELA-PAGA']; 

foreach($parcelaPaga as $parcela) {
    echo $parcela['NUMERO-PARCELA'] . PHP_EOL; 
}
```

Here's an [example](https://implode.io/bDuvvH) you can play with.

Comment: This is also a great help! Thank´s a LOT @Mozammil